# Yii - Remove id field from a form

Tags: php, forms, yii, crud, yii2-advanced-app

I have created a table with the following fields:

```
id - (Primary Key, AUTO-INCREMENT),
receiver_name,
receiver_email,
subject,
content,
attachment
```

I used Gii to create the model and CRUD Generator.
In the view/emails/_form.php there is an ID field.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'id')->textInput() ?>
```

If simply removed from the form, I get the error:

> Missing required parameters: id

Answer (score 1):

So the ID field was included in the model's rules() function.
I simply removed it.
Then removed the field from the _form.php file.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ajvr, however in my opinion if the table is created well and the id is an auto increment, gii should not have the id as a required field.

Comment: Thanks @komu_Mkeya. One for the Yii guys to look into perhaps!

Comment: This has been taken care of in latest version of yii